# How do I select questions viewed over 500,000 times?

Tags: discussion, views

How do I select questions viewed over 500,000 times, such as this one?

[image: Screenshot of a question viewed over 600,000 times]

Comment: There is the stack exchange data explorer. Or sort by views on the question list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in the Help Center Page, *[How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)*:

> `views:500..1000` or `views:500-1000` will return posts with 500 to 1000 views

This is also documented when you do a search and then click the "Advanced Search Tips" link:

[image]

Which is where the link to the help center can be found. In your case you're probably looking for `views:500000`.